# boolean function to know position of mousebutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

is it possible to check the state of the mousebutton (pressed or released). I know that this is the purpose of the eventhandling in jquery, but I wonder if it would be possible to do a function if the button of the mouse isn't pressed without the need of a change in position of the button (pressed to released or vice versa)?

Comment: No, this doesn't really make a lot of sense. The browser doesn't expose that sort of model, one that's continually monitoring everything. Rather, the state of the world is captured when an event happens, and handed over to any registered handlers. Furthermore, the event information captured is usually just that which is relevant to the event type.

Comment: Can you rephrase. I've read this four times and still don't get it. (maybe it's just me)

Comment: Did I misunderstand or are you looking to be able to get the state of the mouse button at any time (not just at the time the mouse button is pressed or released)?

Comment: indeed that was what i wanted to do thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code, [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/J9j6s/) here

```
$(document).mousedown (function () {
    $('#result').text('Pressed');
}).mouseup (function () {
    $('#result').text('Released');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mousedown` and `mouseup` event to detect changed mouse events. This event should be bound to `window`. **Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uwzbn/**

```
var mouseState = (function(){
    var mousestatus = 0;
    $(window).mousedown(function(e) {
        mousestatus = e.which;
    }).mouseup(function(e){
        mousestatus = 0;
    });
    return function() {
        return mousestatus;
    }
})();
```

This function returns four possible values:

```
0  Mouse released   false 
1  Left click       true
2  Middle click     true
3  Right click      true
```

In a boolean context, the function return's value evaluates to false when the mouse is not down. When the mouse is pressed, you can read which mouse key is pressed (as a bonus).

Comment: I wonder if this is too clever for your own good, if I press down 2 buttons, and release one, the state will be 0 even if I still have one button down :p

Comment: @Esailija All of the current answers are suffering from this problem. Afaik, there's no reliable solution for this: The opposite is also possible, you can open a contextmenu, and release the mouse inside the menu. The mouse status would then be stuck at 3.

Comment: well you could overcome it by a bit more complex code (far less complex if you are just tracking a boolean ) but that contextmenu thing cannot be overcame though.

Comment: @Esailija It's not (very) complex: Just increase an internal counter when the keydown event happens, and decrease the counter when the `mouseup` event occurs. However, there are many ways to break this code. Examples: Contextmenu, using keyboard to navigate to another tab, ...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {

    //setup flag for the state of the mouse button and create an object that converts an event type into a boolean for the flag
    var mousePressed = false,
        mouseConvert = {
            mousedown : true,
            mouseup   : false
        };

    //bind to the document's mousedown and mouseup events to change the flag when necessary
    $(document).on('mousedown mouseup', function (event) {

        //set the flag to the new state of the mouse button
        mousePressed = mouseConvert[event.type];

        //if you only want to watch one mouse button and not all of them then
        //you can create an if/then statement here that checks event.which
        //and only updates the flag if it is the button you want, check-out Rob W.'s
        //answer to see the different values for event.which with respect to the mouse
    });
    //now you can check the value of the `mousePressed` variable, if it is equal to `true` then the mouse is currently pressed
});
```